# Гибридные базы данных

Tags: база-данных

Есть классические базы данных, которые хранят информацию на диске, а есть in-memory базы данных, которые хранят все данные в оперативной памяти, а дисковое пространство используют для снапшотов и логирования. Но меня интересуют гибридные базы данных, которые могут держать и обрабатывать данные как в оперативке, так и на диске.

Мне нужно чтобы база данных могла:

1)Хранить все данные в оперативке в случае если оперативной памяти достаточно.

2) В случае если оперативки недостаточно, то  используя алгоритмы кэширования(LRU к примеру), хранить в оперативке только самую актуальную информацию, а все остальное хранить на диске.

Я знаю только одну базу данных, которая соответствует этим критериям- это Extremedb, но она платная, собственно вопрос какие вы знаете гибридные базы данных, которые соответствуют этим критериям?

Comment: Классические РСУБД, такие как Sql Server и Oracle, отвечают вашим требованиям. Они кэшируют в памяти всё, что туда влезет.

Comment: Дело в том, что данные могут меняться быстро, из-за этого кэширование, которое используется в стандартных базах данных не поможет.